# Список "аккордеон", data-target

Tags: html, bootstrap, thymeleaf

Приветствую, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способ реализации ниже приведенной задачи:

**Задача:** имеется список элементов(платежи в системе, количество их зараннее не известно), он обновляется/добавляется автоматически по оплате. При нажатии на элемент, должен выпадать «аккордеон» с подробной информацией о платеже.

**Проблема:** при нажатии на любой существующий платеж, открывается первый и только первый элемент из всего списка… 
если, я правильно понимаю, то, у каждого элемента для открытия должен быть уникальный id… такой синтаксис не правильный.

**Использую:** Thymleaf, Bootstrap

```
<tr th:each="pay: ${pays}">
                <td colspan="7">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#${pay.id}" class="clickable glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></a>
```

или это решается совсем другим образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для каждого [аккордеона](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) нужен уникальный идентификатор. Этот идентификатор прописывается в `data-parent` для каждой панели этого аккордеона.

Но, если я правильно понял вашу задачу, вам нужны не аккордеоны, а просто [сворачивающиеся панели](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example).

Впрочем, для них тоже нужны уникальные идентификаторы. Они прописываются в `href` и `aria-controls`. Например:

```
<tr th:each="pay: ${pays}">
    <td colspan="7">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#${pay.id}" data-toggle="collapse" class="clickable glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="${pay.id}"></a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="${pay.id}">
                        <div class="well">
                          ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Да, думаю они больше подойдут... Спасибо Вам большое)